# Is customising UISearchField is private

Tags: ios, app-store, uisearchbar, appstore-approval

I need to customise UISearchBar:

- Change search text color
- Change favicon

There is no API provided by Apple. However, this is one of possible solution:

```
for(UIView *subView in _searchBar.subviews){
    if([subView isKindOfClass:UITextField.class]){
        UITextField *searchField = (UITextField*)subView;
        searchField.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"loop.png"];
        UIImageView *iView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        searchField.leftView = iView;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly. But I worry that Apple may reject the app. I know this is not a private API, but also this is not fully public.

Does any one have app in App Store with such kind of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not calling any private API, so I'm almost sure that this code will pass the AppStore validation. Take note that your code is not future proof, it is possible that Apple will change the inner `UISearchBar` implementation and your code *might* stop working. The most reliable solution would be to subclass `UITextField` and roll out your own code.

Having said that, it is highly unlikely that this will become a problem, and it's a safe bet that your code will work.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But I need absolutely sure. I want to hear someone who has app with such kind of code in App Store.

Comment: @Artem Kalachev - I have similar code in the app store.  The key is to write it defensively so that if the internals change your app wont break.

Comment: I have this ugly hack in my apps as well. No issues so far.

Answer (score 1):

in most case it would not be detected by apple. (too many apps use similar methods to modify UIControl)
but you need to check iOS version before run this code, apple dev team may change these inner structure in new iOS versions.

```
if (ios > 5.0 && ios < 6.0 )
     // your modifies here
else 
     // ....
```